# Как прочитать только необходимые столбы таблицы в CSV файле?

Tags: python, csv

Файл `csv` состоит из заголовка и таблицы. Подсчет столбцов начинается с 0. Каждый столбец разделён запятыми и количество клеток таблицы в каждой строке одинаковое. Каждая строчка в столбце начинается и заканчивается с кавычек. В таблице есть пустые клетки, состоящие из закрытых кавычек. Из модулей доступны только

```
from typing import TextIO, Dict, Tuple, List, Set, Optional
```

Необходимо считать 1, 13 и 17 столбцы. Условие функции: файл уже открыт.

На фото изображен открытый файл `csv` в питоне и подчеркнуты клетки столбцов которые нужно найти:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def read_csv_file(self, input_file: TextIO) -> None:
    """ Precondition: input_file is an open csv file.
    """
```

Функция необходима для прочитывания разных файлов такого формата.

Comment: _подчеркнуты клетки столбцов которые нужно найти_ так вам нужны столбцы целиком или определенные строки?

Comment: необходимо полностью прочитать 1, 13 и 17 столбцы. на фото просто примеры информации в этих столбах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну по идее должно быть как-то так:

```
for line in input_file:
    columns = line.split(',')
    print(columns[1], columns[13], columns[17])
```

Но если в каком-то столбце запятая попадётся в строке внутри кавычек, то так не получится, нужно тогда регулярками вытаскивать.

И вы не написали, что делать то с вытащенными значениями. Функция ничего не возвращает, судя по сигнатуре, значит она либо печатает, либо собирает в какие-то внутренние поля класса информацию.

Comment: да она собирает поля для класса, мне просто нужно был способ считать именно все клетки в этих столбах.

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) и обратите внимание на параметр  `usecols`.

> **usecols** list-like or callable, optional
>
> Return a subset of the columns. If list-like, all elements must either
> be positional (i.e. integer indices into the document columns) or
> strings that correspond to column names provided either by the user in
> names or inferred from the document header row(s). If names are given,
> the document header row(s) are not taken into account. For example, a
> valid list-like usecols parameter would be [0, 1, 2] or ['foo', 'bar',
> 'baz']. Element order is ignored, so usecols=[0, 1] is the same as [1,
> 0]. To instantiate a DataFrame from data with element order preserved
> use pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo', 'bar'])[['foo', 'bar']] for
> columns in ['foo', 'bar'] order or pd.read_csv(data, usecols=['foo',
> 'bar'])[['bar', 'foo']] for ['bar', 'foo'] order.
>
> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
> column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
> True. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
> x.upper() in ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD']. Using this parameter results in
> much faster parsing time and lower memory usage.

Comment: для этой задачи я не могу импортировать другие модули, только TextIO